# Mercurial repository for OpenProject

Tags: mercurial, openproject

just curious to know if anyone has managed to connect/setup a mercurial repository to work with [OpenProject](https://community.openproject.org/projects/openproject/). I believe OpenProject supports GIT & Subversion natively, but I cannot seem to get it working with Mercurial(Hg).

Any ideas, is there a plugin that does the job?

Answer (score 1):

one of the developers from OpenProject here.

Short answer: There is no current built-in functionality for Mercurial (only Subversion and Git created through OpenProject), but adding your own as a plugin is not that difficult. [There is a ticket](https://community.openproject.org/work_packages/2291/activity) on our community page but its sadly been sitting there on the wishlist for quite a while.

I was responsible for [the repository management overhaul of OpenProject 5.0](https://www.openproject.org/open-source/release-notes/openproject-5-0-0/enhanced-repository-management/) which introduce a number of improvements to both managing and implementing revision management tools for OpenProject.

If you do have some experience with Ruby, you can use [my Gitolite integration plugin](https://github.com/oliverguenther/openproject-revisions_git/tree/release/5.0) for OpenProject as a basis for a new plugin that integrates Mercurial.

The core adapters for Subversion and Git both leverage their command line counterparts to read data on contents, revisions, branches, and so on.

You can also join in at the forums to make that topic more prominent and maybe find a member from the community to work on that integration (e.g., this thread here: https://community.openproject.org/topics/5501?board_id=6&r=5663)

Comment: it would be really nice if you guys add support for mercurial,
we are currently using redmine with HG repo, and planning to switch to openproject, we prefer hg because of easy to extend and add hooks on commits etc. that's one of the reason Facebook uses HG to store their code.

Answer (score 0):

Any Mercurial can easy work with Git-repos (but reverse direction is badly supported from Git's side): I **strongly advise do not use SVN-access** for GitHub's Git repositories (while it possible theoretically with hgsubversion)

You just have to install, read docs, understand and use [HG-Git extension](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/), which allow to clone, pull from and push to remote Git-repositories from Mercurial as easy, as you do it for remote Mercurial repositories with minimal annoyances (slightly changes in repo-URL and not perfect review on incoming in THG)

Answer (score 0):

I've used repos from github with HG-Git extension with HG locally, however, it works fine until you deal with forked repos